# Toggle dropdown on click out of element in react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello I'am implementing my own InputDropdown component on bootstrap-react to give user ability input item or choose it from filtered list.
It's works pretty fine, but to hide dropdown on click out of element, I added onBlur event on FormControl which conflicted with onSelect event in Dropdown. Dropdown closes faster then onSelect occur. 
So, I added setTimeout in onBlur handler and now it's waiting 100ms before attempting to close Dropdown.Menu.
Can I do that and isn't there beter solution?
[Full code on CodePen](https://codepen.io/TogusaRusso/pen/Rggvrd)

```
class InputDrop extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      text: props.item?props.item.name: '',
      open: false,
      show: !!props.item
    }
    const methods = ['toggleDropdown', 'textChange', 'onSelect', 'onKeyUp', 'stopShow', 'onBlur']
    methods.forEach(methodName => this[methodName] = this[methodName].bind(this))
  }
  toggleDropdown() {
    if(this.state.text && this.state.open) return
    if (!this.state.open) this.inputItem.focus()
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open})
  }
  onBlur() {
    setTimeout(() => (this.state.open && 
                      this.setState({open: false, text: ''})), 100)
  }
  onSelect(eventKey) {
    const index = this.props.items.findIndex(item => item.id == eventKey)
    const item = this.props.items[index]
    this.setState({
      open: false,
      text: item.name,
      show: true,
    })
    this.props.onResult(item)
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.show) return <Button onClick={this.stopShow}>{this.state.text}</Button>
    const items = this.state.open ? this.filteredItems() : null
    return (
      <Dropdown
        onSelect={this.onSelect}
        open = {this.state.open && items.length}>
        <InputGroup>
          <FormControl 
            type='text'
            value={this.state.text}
            onClick={this.toggleDropdown}
            onKeyUp={this.onKeyUp}
            onBlur={this.onBlur}
            inputRef={ref => this.inputItem = ref}
            onChange = {this.textChange}/>
          <InputGroup.Addon onClick={this.toggleDropdown}>
              <Glyphicon glyph="triangle-bottom" />
          </InputGroup.Addon>
        </InputGroup>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
          {items && items.map((item, index) => (
            <MenuItem key={item.id} eventKey={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code in your `onSelect` function:

```
this.setState({
  open: false,
  text: item.name,
  show: true,
})
```

to:

```
this.setState({
      // open: false,
      text: item.name,
      show: true,
    }, this.state.open && this.setState({open: false, text: ''}))
```

and remove your onBlur function.

Comment: I removed onBlur event. Now InputDrop don't detect clicks outside dropdown menu and don't close it when this happening. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/TogusaRusso/pen/eREagv)